# SQL table name with spaces

Tags: mysql, sql

I get an error trying this command:

```
CREATE TABLE "Database Name"
(c1 int primary key,
c2 int);
```

I think it's because of the bad table naming. How can I make it work?

Comment: Don't do it.  If you have to -- say if firearms or ransomed close family members are involved -- then use backticks.  Also, your syntax is mixing up `create table` and `create `database`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you want to create table not database:

```
CREATE TABLE `Table Name`(
     c1 INT PRIMARY KEY,
     c2 INT
);
```

Use backticks to quote the name.

[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d17d5/1/0)

Comment: where you got that `<kbd>` tag?   And let me know if you need help with the ransom money.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza hehehehehe. I got <kbd> from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)